# vimgrep: Search from 'tags' file location

Tags: vimgrep

Is there a simple way to setup a binding that will `:vimgrep` up until a `tags` file is found?

I'm curious because I can do `set tags=tags;/` to do a similar search to define tags, but am not quite sure how to transfer this to a different use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a function that will return the directory where the `tags` file is located, by performing the same kind of lookup up the tree.

You can use [`findfile()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#findfile%28%29) or [`finddir()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#finddir%28%29) for this purpose, both will use a lookup method similar to the one used in the `'tags'` option. See [`:help file-searching`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#file-searching) for more details on file searching syntax and a more complete list of functions and options that support that syntax.

For example, you can find the `tags` file up the tree using:

```
:echo findfile('tags', '.;')
```

You can get the path to the directory where the `tags` file using [`fnamemodify()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#fnamemodify%28%29):

```
:echo fnamemodify(findfile('tags', '.;'), ':p:h')
```

And you can use that expression to execute a `:vimgrep` starting on that directory. You'll need `:execute` to build the command from a string:

```
:execute 'vimgrep /something/ '
    \ . fnamemodify(findfile('tags', '.;'), ':p:h')
    \ . '/**'
```

You can easily adapt that to write a function or user-defined command starting the search at the expected directory.

**UPDATE:** In order to bind a key combination to searching from the directory where your `tags` file is, you can either use `:execute` or create an `<expr>` mapping.

For example:

```
nnoremap <Leader>s
    \ :execute "vimgrep /"
    \ . escape(input('/'), '/') . "/ "
    \ . fnamemodify(findfile('tags', '.;'), ':p:h') 
    \ . "/**"<CR>
```

The final `<CR>` executes the Ex command right away. Input is being escaped so that `/` characters are allowed.

An alternative, using `<expr>`, would be:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>s
    \ ":vimgrep /" . escape(input('/'), '/') . "/ "
    \ . fnamemodify(findfile('tags', '.;'), ':p:h') 
    \ . "/**\<CR>"
```

This time we're using a string with `:` so it enters Ex mode first. We're also including the final `<CR>` inside the string with a `"\<CR>"` (using `"\r"` would also be possible, it's equivalent.)

Either approach would do what you want.

**UPDATE 2:** If you're interested in searching relative to where you found the `tags` file in specific, then consider using the [`tagfiles()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#tagfiles%28%29) function to get the path of the one you're using.

Something like this would work:

```
nnoremap <Leader>s
    \ :execute "vimgrep /"
    \ . escape(input('/'), '/') . "/ "
    \ . fnamemodify(tagfiles()[0], ':p:h') 
    \ . "/**"<CR>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly the direction that I was looking for. When using `<expr>` to be able to map this to a key combination and input "something" in the middle, would I also have to use execute?

Comment: @ThoseKind It depends... Your question is a bit vague regarding what you actually want to have in the end. If you're able to explain that in more details (example: a mapping that will prompt for a search term/look up the word under the cursor using `vimgrep` on all the `*.c` or `*.h` files starting up the tree where the `tags` file is found) then you might get a more concrete answer...

Comment: CtrlP allows you to define "root" files from which something like a tags search can start from. Using this idea, I want to do something along these lines without plugins, as a simple mapping to "grep from where the nearest tags file is found searching upwards", but allow input along the way. Something like:

`nnoremap <expr> <Leader>s <esc>:exec ":vimgrep /" . input("") . "/ " . fnamemodify(findfile('tags', ';'), ':p:h') . "/**"`

This works if I just put the `:exec ...` part as a command, but I can't seem to get it to work for mapping to a key combination.

Comment: I have a habit of being vague apparently, but my question is:

`:exec ":vimgrep /" . input("") . "/ " . fnamemodify(findfile('tags', ';'), ':p:h') . "/**"`

works exactly as I want when input as a command. But I am having trouble mapping this to a key binding.

Comment: Ahh, turns out I don't need the `:execute part` if I am mapping with `<expr>`. So the resulting mapping is: `noremap <expr> <Leader>s "<ESC>:vimgrep /" . input("") . "/ " . fnamemodify(findfile('tags', ';'), ':p:h') . "/**<ESC>"`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I refined your final attempt and updated the answer. I suggest you update your question with something like "I want to search starting from where something like a tags search starts from" as that's more clear to what your actual intent is.

Comment: If you're looking for the `tags` files specifically, then consider using the [`tagfiles()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#tagfiles%28%29) function to get the path of the one you're using...